# How to free space from local minishift environment?

Tags: minishift, syndesis

I've followed the [FAQ](https://syndesis.io/faq/#how-to-clean-a-local-minishift-installation) to free space from local `minishift` `syndesis` environment. However, still the `minishift status` shows disk usage above 80%. Any further hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to free up more space by connecting `docker` to the local [minishift daemon](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/docker-daemon.html) and checked the disk consumption:

```
squake:/tmp $ docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                    RECLAIMABLE
Images              24                  22                  7.92GB              2.295GB (28%)
Containers          159                 54                  1.106GB             1.105GB (99%)
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

So that I managed to prune all unused containers:

```
docker container prune
```

Reducing from 85% to less than 50%:

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the syndesis cmdline tool (https://doc.syndesis.io/#syndesis-dev) and issue

```
syndesis dev --cleanup
```